# How to convert a coarse raster to a smooth polygon

Tags: r, raster, spatial, netcdf, terra

Say you have a `raster`, could be e.g. [Sea Surface Temperature from NOAA](https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2.highres/) with a grid: 0.25 degree latitude x 0.25 degree longitude global grid (1440x720).

Is it possible to convert a raster like this with R, so the output is smooth `polygons`? [This would be an example from NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2023/us/smoke-maps-canada-fires.html) where similar coarse raster files where somehow converted to 3 classes of smooth polygons.

Is there a clever way? I tried a lot with `disaggregate`, `focal`, `reclassify`, `terra: aspolygons`, `smoothr:smooth`

Nothing is really close to a smooth polygon. Any clues?

Here is a screenshot from the NYTimes [image: NYTimes polygons for smoke plume]

Comment: The NYT example appears to be paywalled - can you screenshot it or provide an alternative example?

Comment: sorry, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible work-flow. First go to a high spatial resolution with `resample`; make polygons; simplify.

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("filename")
x <- disagg(x, 10, method="bilinear")
# reclassify to get NA and one other value, e.g.
x <- ifel(x < 1, NA, 1) 
p <- as.polygons(x)
s <- simplifyGeoms(p)
```